# 403 Forbidden when trying to install arcgis-java dependency with maven

Tags: java, maven, arcgis

I have followed the guide in https://developers.arcgis.com/java/latest/guide/get-the-sdk.htm but somehow I got this 404 forbidden error when trying to run `mvn install` to install the dependencies of my project (there's ArcGIS, and it's the core problem).

```
$ mvn install 
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] -----------------------< redacted >-----------------------
[INFO] Building <redacted> 1.1
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
Downloading from arcgis: https://esri.bintray.com/arcgis/com/esri/arcgisruntime/arcgis-java/100.8.0/arcgis-java-100.8.0.pom
Downloading from arcgis: https://esri.bintray.com/arcgis/com/esri/arcgisruntime/arcgis-java-jnilibs/100.8.0/arcgis-java-jnilibs-100.8.0.pom
Downloading from arcgis: https://esri.bintray.com/arcgis/com/esri/arcgisruntime/arcgis-java-resources/100.8.0/arcgis-java-resources-100.8.0.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  7.135 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-01-11T14:38:29+07:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project <redacted>: Could not resolve dependencies for project <redacted>:jar:1.1: Failed to collect dependencies at com.esri.arcgisruntime:arcgis-java:jar:100.8.0: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.esri.arcgisruntime:arcgis-java:jar:100.8.0: Could not transfer artifact com.esri.arcgisruntime:arcgis-java:pom:100.8.0 from/to arcgis (https://esri.bintray.com/arcgis): Authorization failed for https://esri.bintray.com/arcgis/com/esri/arcgisruntime/arcgis-java/100.8.0/arcgis-java-100.8.0.pom 403 Forbidden -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

When I tried to open the URL https://esri.bintray.com/arcgis/com/esri/arcgisruntime/arcgis-java/100.8.0/arcgis-java-100.8.0.pom in my browser, I also got that 404 forbidden error. I think the link is broken somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by replacing the ArcGIS repo's URL from

`https://esri.bintray.com/arcgis`

to

`https://esri.jfrog.io/artifactory/arcgis`

in my project's `pom.xml`.

That repo URL (the latter) is used in [ArcGIS Android installation guide](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/latest/guide/install-and-set-up.htm), but somehow, the [argis-java's documentation](https://developers.arcgis.com/java/latest/guide/get-the-sdk.htm) doesn't include this and instead include the former one which is broken (returns 404 forbidden error)

EDIT:

I just found an announcement about this issue, my bad, I didn't see this at the first time. So yes, they moved their repository from the former one to the latter. https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/developers/announcements/announcement-to-developers-using-arcgis-runtime-sdks-for-android-and-java/